# Is there anything wrong with the usage of "the more exciting" this sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence, syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns

> Nearly all of the editors of the magazine agree that of the two articles to be published, Fujimura's is **the more exciting**.

Shouldn't it be "the more exciting *one*"?

Comment: I guess it is understood even without mentioning *one* at the end.

Comment: It is extremely common in English for "understood" words not to be written or said. And often the flow of the language is much better without the additional words.  So your sample sentence is completely okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use *one* as not using it is idiomatic. The definite article *the* is used before a comparative when you compare two things or people and usually ***of the two*** is used or omitted at the end.

> Nearly all of the editors of the magazine agree that ***of the two***
>   articles to be published, Fujimura's is ***the*** more exciting (***of the two***).

*Of the two* is omitted because it was used before.

Other examples:

> This book is ***the more interesting*** of the two.
>   Who is taller, Tom or
>   Dick? Tom is ***the taller*** of the two.

You don't use ***one*** in the above examples.

Comment: Just to clarify  the definite article "the" is not required in the sample sentences, in order to retain common idiomatic form. You could say: *Who is taller, Tom or Dick? Tom is taller.* In this form however, there are no understood words omitted.

Comment: @Cargill Yes, people would have no problem in understanding *Tom is taller*. The OP asks if *one* should be used and I am explaining that it shouldn't be used.

Comment: And I am assisting in that explanation, with some clarification.